# Можно ли в QNetworkRequest задать кодировку?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qnetworkrequest

Можно ли в QNetworkRequest задать кодировку? А то я загружаю с помощью него сайт а там вместо русских букв кракозяблы.

```
void Downloader::getData(QString str)
{
    whatdownloaded = 1;
    QUrl url(str); // URL, к которому будем получать данные

    QNetworkRequest request;    // Отправляемый запрос
    request.setUrl(url);        // Устанавлвиваем URL в запрос
    manager->get(request);      // Выполняем запрос
}


void Downloader::onResult(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    // Если в процесе получения данных произошла ошибка
    if(reply->error()){
        // Сообщаем об этом и показываем информацию об ошибках
        qDebug() << "ERROR";
        qDebug() << reply->errorString();
    } else {
        QByteArray str = reply->readAll();
        QString str2(str);//тут на месте русских букв кракозяблы ? и т.д
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны верно конвертировать полученный QByteArray в QString, указав правильную кодировку. 
Для этого можно воспользоваться функцией хелпером [QString::fromUtf8](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromUtf8-1), написав так

```
QString str2 = QString::fromUtf8(str)
```

Она преобразует массив байт в строку с кодировкой UTF-8.

Если вам нужна какая-то специфичная кодировка, то для этого можно воспользоваться классом [QTextCodec](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcodec.html).

```
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("Windows-1251");
QString str2 = codec->toUnicode(str1);
```

Функция `codecForName` принимает аргументом строку с названием кодировки. По ссылке выше вы найдете список поддерживаемых кодировок.

Comment: Cпс только вот что то не помогло сайт какой то странный https://www.webapteka.ru/drugbase_alpha/letter1.html скодировал в Windows-1251 (собственно это и есть кодировка этого сайта), получил русские буквы, только вот там абракадавра из русских букв, что это может быть не знаете?

Comment: вот этот [сайт](http://validator.w3.org) говорит, что кодировка данной страницы koi8-r. Попробуйте пжлста с этой кодировкой QTextCodec

Comment: Заработало, опять я протупил, глянул кодировку в коде стр charset, windows-1251 а это же не настоящая кодировка