# Приходят крикозябры с Википедии. Как указать кодировку данных которые приходят с этого сайта?

Tags: qt, парсер, кодировка, mediawiki-api

Я использую API wikimedia, для формирования запроса на парсинг раздела:[https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Ключевая%20ставка%20в%20России&rvprop=content&rvsection=1&format=xml](https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=%D0%9A%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%20%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8&rvprop=content&rvsection=1&format=xml)

Но в Qt приходят крикозябры:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><api batchcomplete=\"\"><warnings><main xml:space=\"preserve\">Unrecognized parameter: utf8.</main></warnings><query><pages><page _idx=\"5056059\" pageid=\"5056059\" ns=\"0\" title=\"РљР»СЋС‡РµРІР°СЏ СЃС‚Р°РІРєР° РІ Р РѕСЃСЃРёРё\"><revisions><rev contentformat=\"text/x-wiki\" contentmodel=\"wikitext\" xml:space=\"preserve\">== Р—РЅР°С‡РµРЅРёСЏ РєР»СЋС‡РµРІРѕР№ СЃС‚Р°РІРєРё РІ Р РѕСЃСЃРёРё ==\n{| class=&quot;wikitable&quot; style=&quot;text-align:center&quot;\n! РџРµСЂРёРѕРґ РґРµР№СЃС‚РІРёСЏ\n! align=&quot;center&quot;| % РіРѕРґРѕРІС‹С…\n! РџСЂРёРјРµС‡Р°РЅРёСЏ\n|-\n| 03.02.2013 вЂ” 02.03.2014 || 5,5 || &lt;ref name=cb14all&gt;[http://www.cbr.ru/DKP/keyrate/rates_table_14/ РџСЂРѕС†РµРЅС‚РЅС‹Рµ СЃС‚Р°РІРєРё РїРѕ РѕРїРµСЂР°С†РёСЏРј Р‘Р°РЅРєР° Р РѕСЃСЃРёРё 2014] / РЎР°Р№С‚ Р¦Р‘ Р Р¤.&lt;/ref&gt;\n|-\n| 03.03.2014 вЂ” 27.04.2014 || 7,0 || &lt;ref name=cb14all/&gt;\n|-\n| 28.04.2014В вЂ” 27.07.2014В || 7,5 || &lt;ref name=cb14all/&gt;\n|-\n| 28.07.2014В вЂ” 04.11.2014В || 8,0 || &lt;ref name=cb14all/&gt;\n|-\n| 05.11.2014В вЂ” 11.12.2014В || 9,5 || &lt;ref name=cb14all/&gt;\n|-\n| 12.12.2014В вЂ” 15.12.2014В || 10,5В || &lt;ref name=cb14all/&gt;\n|-\n| 16.12.2014В вЂ” 01.02.2015В || 17,0В || &lt;ref name=cb14all/&gt;\n|-\n| 02.02.2015В вЂ” 15.03.2015В || 15,0В || &lt;ref name=cb15all&gt;[http://www.cbr.ru/DKP/keyrate/rates_table_15/ РџСЂРѕС†РµРЅС‚РЅС‹Рµ СЃС‚Р°РІРєРё РїРѕ РѕРїРµСЂР°С†РёСЏРј Р‘Р°РЅРєР° Р РѕСЃСЃРёРё 2015] / РЎР°Р№С‚ Р¦Р‘ Р Р¤.&lt;/ref&gt;&lt;ref&gt;[http://www.dp.ru/a/2015/01/30/CB_snizhaet_kljuchevuju_stavk/ Р¦Р‘ СЃРЅРёР¶Р°РµС‚ РєР»СЋС‡РµРІСѓСЋ СЃС‚Р°РІРєСѓ РґРѕ 15В % СЃ РЅР°С‡Р°Р»Р° С„РµРІСЂР°Р»СЏ&lt;!-- Р—Р°РіРѕР»РѕРІРѕРє РґРѕР±Р°РІР»РµРЅ Р±РѕС‚РѕРј --&gt;]&lt;/ref&gt;\n|-\n| 16.03.2015В вЂ” 04.05.2015В || 14,0В || &lt;ref name=cb15all/&gt;&lt;ref&gt;{{Cite web|url = http://russian.rt.com/article/79319|title = Р¦Р‘ Р Р¤ РїРѕРЅРёР·РёР» РєР»СЋС‡РµРІСѓСЋ СЃС‚Р°РІРєСѓ РґРѕ 14%|author = |work = |date = 13.03.2015|publisher = RT РЅР° СЂСѓСЃСЃРєРѕРј}}&lt;/ref&gt;\n|-\n| 05.05.2015В вЂ” 15.06.2015В || 12,5В || &lt;ref name=cb15all/&gt;&lt;ref&gt;{{Cite web|url = http://www.cbr.ru/press/pr.aspx?file=30042015_133103dkp2015-04-30T13_05_21.htm|title = Рћ РєР»СЋС‡РµРІРѕР№ СЃС‚Р°РІРєРµ Р‘Р°РЅРєР° Р РѕСЃСЃРёРё (РїРѕРЅРёР¶РµРЅРёРµ 30 Р°РїСЂРµР»СЏ 2015 c 14,00% РґРѕ 12,50%)|author = |work = |date = |publisher = РЎР°Р№С‚ Р¦Р‘ Р Р¤ }}&lt;/ref&gt;\n|-\n| 16.06.2015В вЂ” 02.08.2015В || 11,5В || &lt;ref name=cb15all/&gt;&lt;ref&gt;{{Cite web|url = http://www.cbr.ru/press/pr.aspx?file=15062015_133028keyrate2015-06-15T13_25_44.htm|title = РЎР°Р№С‚ Р¦Р‘ Р Р¤. Рћ РєР»СЋС‡РµРІРѕР№ СЃС‚Р°РІРєРµ Р‘Р°РЅРєР° Р РѕСЃСЃРёРё (РїРѕРЅРёР¶РµРЅРёРµ СЃ 16.06.2015 РґРѕ 11,5% РіРѕРґРѕРІС‹С…).|author = |work = |date = |publisher = }}&lt;/ref&gt;\n|-\n| 03.08.2015В вЂ” 13.06.2016В || 11,0В || &lt;ref name=cb15all/&gt;&lt;ref&gt;{{cite web|url=http://www.cbr.ru/press/PR.aspx?file=31072015_133033keyrate2015-07-31T13_03_35.htm|title=Рћ РєР»СЋС‡РµРІРѕР№ СЃС‚Р°РІРєРµ Р‘Р°РЅРєР° Р РѕСЃСЃРёРё|date=2015-07-31|publisher=Р¦Р‘ Р Р¤}}&lt;/ref&gt;&lt;ref&gt;[http://www.cbr.ru/press/keypr.aspx Р‘Р°РЅРє Р РѕСЃСЃРёРё СЃРѕС…СЂР°РЅРёР» РєР»СЋС‡РµРІСѓСЋ СЃС‚Р°РІРєСѓ РЅР° СѓСЂРѕРІРЅРµ 11,00В % РіРѕРґРѕРІС‹С…] / РџСЂРµСЃСЃ-СЃР»СѓР¶Р±Р° Р‘Р°РЅРєР° Р РѕСЃСЃРёРё, 11 РґРµРєР°Р±СЂСЏ 2015 РіРѕРґР° &lt;/ref&gt;\n|-\n| 14.06.2016В вЂ” 18.09.2016В || 10,5В || &lt;ref name=&quot;cb16all&quot;&gt;[http://www.cbr.ru/DKP/keyrate/rates_table_16/ РџСЂРѕС†РµРЅС‚РЅС‹Рµ СЃС‚Р°РІРєРё РїРѕ РѕРїРµСЂР°С†РёСЏРј Р‘Р°РЅРєР° Р РѕСЃСЃРёРё 2016] / РЎР°Р№С‚ Р¦Р‘ Р Р¤.&lt;/ref&gt;\n|-\n| 19.09.2016В вЂ” 26.03.2017В || 10,0В || &lt;ref name=&quot;cb16all&quot;/&gt;&lt;ref name=&quot;cb17all&quot;/&gt;\n|-\n| 27.03.2017В вЂ” 01.05.2017В || 9,75 || &lt;ref name=&quot;cb17all&quot;&gt;[http://www.cbr.ru/DKP/keyrate/rates_table_17/ РџСЂРѕС†РµРЅС‚РЅС‹Рµ СЃС‚Р°РІРєРё РїРѕ РѕРїРµСЂР°С†РёСЏРј Р‘Р°РЅРєР° Р РѕСЃСЃРёРё 2017] / РЎР°Р№С‚ Р¦Р‘ Р Р¤.&lt;/ref&gt;&lt;ref&gt;{{cite web|url=http://www.cbr.ru/press/PR.aspx?file=24032017_132958keyrate2017-03-24T13_25_44.htm |ti
tle=Р‘Р°РЅРє Р РѕСЃСЃРёРё РїСЂРёРЅСЏР» СЂРµС€РµРЅРёРµ СЃРЅРёР·РёС‚СЊ РєР»СЋС‡РµРІСѓСЋ СЃС‚Р°РІРєСѓ РґРѕ 9,75% РіРѕРґРѕРІС‹С… |date=2017-03-24 |publisher=Р¦Р‘ Р Р¤ |accessdate=2017-03-27}}&lt;/ref&gt;\n|-\n| 02.05.2017 вЂ” 18.06.2017 || 9,25 || &lt;ref name=&quot;cb17all&quot;/&gt;&lt;ref&gt;{{Cite web|url=http://www.cbr.ru/press/pr.aspx?file=28042017_132959keyrate2017-04-28T13_17_20.htm|title=Р‘Р°РЅРє Р РѕСЃСЃРёРё РїСЂРёРЅСЏР» СЂРµС€РµРЅРёРµ СЃРЅРёР·РёС‚СЊ РєР»СЋС‡РµРІСѓСЋ СЃС‚Р°РІРєСѓ РґРѕ 9,25% РіРѕРґРѕРІС‹С…|publisher=www.cbr.ru|accessdate=2017-04-28}}&lt;/ref&gt;\n|-\n|19.06.2017 вЂ” 17.09.2017 || 9,0 ||&lt;ref name=&quot;cb17all&quot;/&gt;&lt;ref&gt;{{Cite web|url=http://www.cbr.ru/press/pr.aspx?file=16062017_133001keyrate2017-06-16T13_21_27.htm|title=Р‘Р°РЅРє Р РѕСЃСЃРёРё РїСЂРёРЅСЏР» СЂРµС€РµРЅРёРµ СЃРЅРёР·РёС‚СЊ РєР»СЋС‡РµРІСѓСЋ СЃС‚Р°РІРєСѓ РґРѕ 9,00% РіРѕРґРѕРІС‹С…|publisher=www.cbr.ru|accessdate=2017-06-16}}&lt;/ref&gt;\n|-\n|18.09.2017 вЂ” 29.10.2017 || 8,5 || &lt;ref name=&quot;cb17all&quot;/&gt;&lt;ref&gt;[http://www.rbc.ru/finances/15/09/2017/59bb99d49a7947fc3cfbf75f Р¦Р‘ СЃРЅРёР·РёР» РєР»СЋС‡РµРІСѓСЋ СЃС‚Р°РІРєСѓ С‡РµС‚РІРµСЂС‚С‹Р№ СЂР°Р· Р·Р° РіРѕРґ вЂ” Р Р‘Рљ]&lt;/ref&gt;\n|-\n|30.10.2017 вЂ” 17.12.2017 || 8,25 || &lt;ref name=&quot;cb17all&quot;/&gt;&lt;ref&gt;{{Cite news|title=Р¦РµРЅС‚СЂРѕР±Р°РЅРє СЃРЅРёР·РёР» РєР»СЋС‡РµРІСѓСЋ СЃС‚Р°РІРєСѓ РІ РїСЏС‚С‹Р№ СЂР°Р· Р·Р° РіРѕРґ|url=http://www.rbc.ru/finances/27/10/2017/59f2f7c59a794718d5968f1b|work=Р Р‘Рљ|accessdate=2017-10-27}}&lt;/ref&gt;\n|-\n|18.12.2017 вЂ” 11.02.2018 || 7,75 || &lt;ref&gt;[http://www.cbr.ru/press/keypr/?Prev=Y Р‘Р°РЅРє Р РѕСЃСЃРёРё РїСЂРёРЅСЏР» СЂРµС€РµРЅРёРµ СЃРЅРёР·РёС‚СЊ РєР»СЋС‡РµРІСѓСЋ СЃС‚Р°РІРєСѓ РЅР° 50 Р±.Рї., РґРѕ 7,75% РіРѕРґРѕРІС‹С…]&lt;/ref&gt;\n|-\n|12.02.2018 вЂ” 25.03.2018\n|7,5\n|&lt;ref&gt;[http://www.cbr.ru/press/PR/?file=09022018_133031keyrate2018-02-09T13_29_29.htm Р‘Р°РЅРє Р РѕСЃСЃРёРё РїСЂРёРЅСЏР» СЂРµС€РµРЅРёРµ СЃРЅРёР·РёС‚СЊ РєР»СЋС‡РµРІСѓСЋ СЃС‚Р°РІРєСѓ РЅР° 25 Р±.Рї., РґРѕ 7,50% РіРѕРґРѕРІС‹С…]&lt;/ref&gt;\n|-\n|26.03.2018 вЂ” РЅ.РІ.\n|7,25\n|&lt;ref&gt;[http://www.cbr.ru/press/PR/?file=23032018_133000keyrate2018-03-23T13_20_35.htm Р‘Р°РЅРє Р РѕСЃСЃРёРё РїСЂРёРЅСЏР» СЂРµС€РµРЅРёРµ СЃРЅРёР·РёС‚СЊ РєР»СЋС‡РµРІСѓСЋ СЃС‚Р°РІРєСѓ РЅР° 25 Р±.Рї., РґРѕ 7,25% РіРѕРґРѕРІС‹С…]&lt;/ref&gt;\n|}</rev></revisions></page></pages></query></api>
```

Как мне указать кодировку и какую? Чтоб кириллица отобразилась нормально. И где надо указать эту кодировку в ссылки или самой программе?

Сам код парсинга с Википедии:

```
...
connect(&theLoader, SIGNAL(dataReadyRead(QTextStream*)),this,SLOT(dataUploader(QTextStream*)));
...
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_4_clicked()
{
    theLoader.makeRequest("https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Ключевая%20ставка%20в%20России&rvprop=content&rvsection=1&format=xml");
}
...
```

loader.h

```
#ifndef LOADER_H
#define LOADER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
class Loader : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Loader(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void makeRequest(QString endPointRequest);
signals:
    void dataReadyRead(QTextStream *data);
public slots:
    void ReadRead(QNetworkReply *reply);
private:
    QNetworkAccessManager *m_manager =new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
};

#endif // LOADER_H
```

loader.cpp

```
#include "loader.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QSslError>
#include <QRegExp>

Loader::Loader(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    connect(m_manager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(ReadRead(QNetworkReply*)));
}

void Loader::makeRequest(QString endPointRequest)
{
    m_manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(endPointRequest)));
}

void Loader::ReadRead(QNetworkReply *wikirep)
{
    QTextStream repStream(wikirep);
    //QString str = repStream.readAll();
    qDebug() << "Response Received:\n" << repStream.readAll();
    //wikirep->deleteLater();

    //QRegExp rx("([\d]{2}\.[\d]{2}\.[\d]{4}...[\d]{2}\.[\d]{2}\.[\d]{4}).{4}([\d,]{2,4})/gm");
    QRegExp rx("cbr");
    int pos = rx.indexIn(repStream.readAll());
    QStringList list = rx.capturedTexts();

    //emit dataReadyRead(&repStream);
}
```

Кто будет тестировать код ,для того чтоб спарсить данные с Википедии, надо выполнить указания по [ссылки](http://codeblog.vurdalakov.net/2009/11/solution-qsslsocket-cannot-call.html) и скопировать две библиотеки из установленной программы лежащие в папке bin, после чего подключить их в pro файле `LIBS += -Llibeay32 -Lssleay32`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для определения кодировки скачиваемой страницы можно воспользоваться вот [этим ресурсом](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fru.wikipedia.org%2Fw%2Fapi.php%3Faction%3Dquery%26prop%3Drevisions%26titles%3D%D0%9A%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F%2520%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%2520%D0%B2%2520%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8%26rvprop%3Dcontent%26rvsection%3D1%26format%3Dxml&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0). Теперь мы знаем кодировку скачиваемой страницы  - **utf-8**.

Далее, в методе `ReadRead` я бы не стал создавать `QtextStream`, а читал бы массив байт из ответа, а потом преобразовал его в строку с кодировкой **utf-8**(для `QtextStream` тоже можно указать кодировку с помощью метода [setCodec](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtextstream.html#setCodec), но я не вижу здесь смысл его использовать)

```
void Loader::ReadRead(QNetworkReply *wikirep)
{
    QByteArray byteStr = wikirep->readAll();
    QString str = QString::fromUtf8(byteStr);
    qDebug() << "Response Received:\n" << str;
    //wikirep->deleteLater();

    //QRegExp rx("([\d]{2}\.[\d]{2}\.[\d]{4}...[\d]{2}\.[\d]{2}\.[\d]{4}).{4}([\d,]{2,4})/gm");
    QRegExp rx("cbr");
    int pos = rx.indexIn(str);
    QStringList list = rx.capturedTexts();

    //emit dataReadyRead(&repStream);
}
```

Также для вас думаю может быть полезен [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/819371/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-qnetworkrequest-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%83/819377#819377) на похожий вопрос.

Comment: Этот вариант надо править: 1 Он обрезает то что приходит с Википедии(думаю это из-за того что какие то ограничения на количество символов в строке). 2 Я не совсем понимаю почему мы тут указали кодировку, а в консоль всё равно выводятся криказябры  ...Êëþ÷åâàÿ ñòàâêà â Ðîññèè...

Comment: [настройте консоль](https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8) для корректного отображения символов в кодировке utf-8. На счет обрезания - сказать точно не могу, надо запускать ваш пример. Но по идее, никаких обрезаний быть не должно.